# how to make multiple xampp server on different pc of same localhost address?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, server, xampp

my title might not be correct but this is what i want to to:

i made a website on wordpress and hosted it locally on one of my college pc(2gb ram, intel core 2 duo), using xampp.

the website is about filling the form for student data. today almost 500 students tried filling it at once, due to which i was getting the below error 
"Apache XAMPP server HAS STOPPED WORKING" 
1. search online
2. close the program.

can anyone suggest me the setting that i should make?
or should i upgrade the pc?

---

or can i make multiple server like more than one pc with xampp installed?

like if one pc with the server fails to respond it should be shifted to another pc with same xampp server or something like this?

but with same database and address.?

Comment: What you are looking for is called `load balancing`

Comment: can you gimme the the link of what i should do?